# Class API design: should I return a field in getXxx() method by value or as a const-ref?

Tags: c++, class

Just a C++ newbie question.
I have a class like

```
class Person
{
  private:
  std::string m_name;
};
```

Is it better to design getter as

```
std::string name() const;
```

so m_name will be copied each time name() is called or as

```
const std::string& name() const;
```

so caller can make his own copy, if he wants.

Comment: It is better design to do neither. The question is why do you want to access the name outside the Person class? If it is for serializing (printing) then you should have a serialization method (or friend function), if it is because it is used for sorting then you should have a comparison function built into your class etc. You should not be exposing members you should be exposing actions.

Comment: @Martin: with appropriate interface to this function, he's exposing a property - it happens to be implemented as a data member, but only the reference return exposes that, the value return doesn't. The Law of Demeter is all very well, but I think not so good enough that we can confidently say that objects which expose properties necessarily are badly designed. Try designing a ORM that way. To re-cast this as an "action", have a `visitName` function on `Person` which takes as parameter a callback which is called once, with one parameter, the name. Does this *really* improve the design?

Comment: @Steve: All true: What it really comes back to is: `The question is **why** do you want to access the name outside the Person class?` Sometimes it is worth providing the access, but to answer the question correctly we must know **WHY** it is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I would go with the const& version, since it avoids unnecessary copying.

However, if you're making a class that's intended to be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, returning a copy is cleaner and more reliable.

Comment: +1 for thread caveat I should have added that as a reason to return a copy in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is to return by value unless it is part of the
contract that you return a reference to something internal (e.g.
like vector<>::operator[]).  In addition to threading issues,
there can easily be lifetime of object issues: if you return
a reference, and the client captures it by reference, then
deletes your object, he's left with a dangling reference.

Return by value does have performance implications.  If these
become a concern, you might want to return by an out argument,
which will also avoid a copy of the filled out object, e.g.:
    void tables(std::vector* result);
I wouldn't do this until I knew I had a performance problem,
however.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's possible to return a reference is dependent on something that's probably an implementation detail, that `name` is stored in the objects as a `std::string`. Conceivably it could be stored differently (perhaps via a char*, or compressed, or in a different character encoding from the one that your `name` function says that it returns), and converted to `std::string` on the fly.

So, do you want to bake this implementation detail into your interface? If not, then you shouldn't even consider returning a reference.